# iText 7 Texts inside a rectangle (Image) in specify position

Tags: vb.net, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I need to fill this image with these values... I already done with "PrintDocument" but you can't automatically export it in PDF... So I'm migrating to iText, but rectangles referentes seens not be the same... While in "PrintDocument" Y value start from top, in iText, they start from bottom...

Old Code:

```
  e.Graphics.DrawString(ParcelaAtual + 1 & " / " & tabParcelas.Rows.Count, Fonte1, Brushes.Black, x + 254, y + 34, Formato1)
```

New Code: (Not working properly)

```
        PdfCanvas = New iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.PdfCanvas(page)
        retangulo = New iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(x + 350, y + 84)
        canvas = New iText.Layout.Canvas(PdfCanvas, pdf, retangulo)
        texto = (New iText.Layout.Element.Text(ParcelaAtual + 1 & " / " & tabParcelas.Rows.Count).SetFontSize(12).SetBold) ' Fonte 1 | Formato 1
        paragrafo = (New iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph().Add(texto))
        canvas.Add(paragrafo)
        canvas.Close()
```

So, I think I'll have to remake this... Catch all X/Y values again and etc etc etc....

I think the best way to do this is to draw an image (rectangle) and inside this image draw the texts, but taking the top/left image border as X/Y reference not the top/left from page border...

Sometimes I need only 1 image with values, sometimes I need 3 of them (as shown in imagem below)...

How can I achieve that? (This image below as drawn with "PrintDocument" but I want to draw it with iText to automatically export in PDF)

[image]

Comment: Writing text on bitmap images here is a bad idea, you get bad looks requiring more space.

Comment: Do you've any suggestion? @mkl

Comment: How about transforming your coordinates? That's simple math.

Comment: I made it 1 by 1... 4 hours of working, but that's fine